# Finding the $x$-coordinate of the vertex of a hyperbola?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

How would I go about finding the $x$-coordinates for the vertex of the hyperbola $y^2 + y = x^2 + 4$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Go about completing that square:

$$\frac{\left(y+\frac12\right)^2}{17/4}-\frac{x^2}{17/4}=1$$

We then know that hyperbolas of the form

$$\frac{(y-h)^2}{a^2}-\frac{(x-k)^2}{b^2}=1$$

have vertexes at $x=k$ (because that is where the graph is symmetric) so for our case, the point in interest lies on $x=0$.

Comment: How did you get that first equation? Also, your answer doesn't agree with the graph I get from the equation through Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: @JaneDoe Complete the square on both sides, then divide both sides by $17/4$.

Comment: @JaneDoe You might want to check your WolframAlpha input.